# How to change a Hunspell affix file to allow numbers in words?

Tags: numbers, letters, affix, hunspell, word-boundary

OCR programs often mistakenly recognize the capital letter O as a zero or vice versa. For example, they might recognize Over as 0ver or well as we11.

I tried to add

```
REP 0 O
REP 1 l
```

to the affix file, but it didn't work because numbers are apparently considered word boundaries.

(I had a look at the [hunspell man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/hunspell), but I can't figure out which of the numerous settings needs to be changed to allow numbers in words.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpages:

REP what replacement
              This table specifies modifications to try first.  First  REP  is
              the  header  of  this  table  and  one or more REP data line are
              following it.  With this table, Hunspell can suggest  the  right
              forms  for the typical spelling mistakes when the incorrect form
              differs by more than 1 letter from the right form.   The  search
              string supports the regex boundary signs (^ and $).  For example
              a  possible  English  replacement  table  definition  to  handle
              misspelled consonants:

```
          REP 5
          REP f ph
          REP ph f
          REP tion$ shun
          REP ^cooccurr co-occurr
          REP ^alot$ a_lot
```

Did you add the first line, REP + number of replacements?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did add the header with the number of following entries and all other REP statements work. What doesn't work is:
`REP 0 O`

Comment: Do you think it might be possible, that hunspell sees REP followed by an integer, and interprets it as a header, instead of a replacement? In that case, placing the zero replacement at the end might work, if it doesn't i'm afraid that's an oversight of the Hunspell implementation.

Comment: You're probably right. The Hunspell parser probably gets confused by numbers in REP statements.